# Django - Regroup By Date

Tags: python, django

I have a model with the following fields: "Date", "Employee", and "Planned Hours". Each employee has various planned hours for various dates.

I'm attempting to structure my template where employees are listed in rows and their planned hours are listed in columns under the correct corresponding date.

I'm currently filtering by two dates. One employee has time for the second date, but not the most current date. I would like his time to be listed correctly under the 2nd date, but currently it's displaying under the current date. See 1 hour for Chase: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYRZd.png

My view:

```
def DesignHubR(request):
emp3_list = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.values_list('displayval', 'employeename').\
filter(businessunit='a').filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Project').filter(Q(displayval=sunday2)|Q(displayval=sunday)).\
annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
emp3 = map(lambda x: {'date': x[0], 'employee_name': x[1], 'planned_hours': x[2]}, emp3_list)
context = {'sunday': sunday, 'emp2': emp2, 'sunday2': sunday2, 'emp3': emp3}
return render(request,'department_hub_ple.html', context)
```

My Template:

```
{% regroup emp3 by employee_name as emp9 %}
{% for employee_name in emp9 %}
<!--Job-->
<div class="table-row table-job-column employee-row">{{employee_name.grouper}}</div>
{% regroup employee_name.list by date|date as date_list %}
{% for y in date_list %}


<div class="table-row table-fr-column">{{y.list.0.planned_hours|default:"0"}}</div>
<div class="table-row table-fr-column">{{y.list.1.planned_hours|default:"0"}}</div>
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

emp3_list Data:

```
[{'date': 'W/E 6/18/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('45.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Waylan'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/25/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('45.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Waylan'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/18/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('17.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Michael'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/25/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('13.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Michael'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/25/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('1.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Chase'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/18/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('27.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Bert'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/25/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('29.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Bert'}]
```

Model:

```
class Projectsummaryplannedhours(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(db_column='Number', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    clientname = models.CharField(db_column='ClientName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    department = models.CharField(db_column='Department', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    billinggroup = models.CharField(db_column='BillingGroup', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    businessunit = models.CharField(db_column='BusinessUnit', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    employeename = models.CharField(db_column='EmployeeName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    displayval = models.CharField(db_column='DisplayVal', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    startofweek = models.DateTimeField(db_column='StartOfWeek', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    endofweek = models.DateTimeField(db_column='EndOfWeek', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    plannedhours = models.DecimalField(db_column='PlannedHours', max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    rateschedule = models.CharField(db_column='RateSchedule', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    classification = models.CharField(db_column='Classification', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dollarsforecast = models.DecimalField(db_column='DollarsForecast', max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    deleted = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='Deleted')  # Field name made lowercase.
    datelastmodified = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateLastModified', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateCreated', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be a solution:
{% for y in date_list %}
  if(y.list.0.date == current_date){
    {{y.list.0.planned_hours|default:"0"}}
    {{y.list.1.planned_hours|default:"0"}}
    {{y.list.2.planned_hours|default:"0"}}
  }else{
    -----
    {{y.list.0.planned_hours|default:"0"}}
    {{y.list.1.planned_hours|default:"0"}}
  }
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}